# Как правильно включить 404 страницу?

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс

На всех страницах сайта если захожу на несуществующую страницу - кидает на 404, все хорошо.
Но есть 1 страница site.ru/club/articles/ которая ведет себя очень странно.
Если добавить site.ru/club/articles/club/ - страница отработает(хотя такой не существует)
Если в htaccess убрать ErrorDocument 404 /404.php то данная страница падает с ошибкой

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.

Почему так работает и как исправить?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
     
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
    RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html|htm)\ HTTP/ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html|htm)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^www.rhanaclinic\.ru/bitrix/admin/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^rhanaclinic/\.ru/bitrix/admin/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.(php|html|htm)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html|htm)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.+)/"
    RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему htaccess речь про сайт rhanaclinic.ru.
Ссылка https://rhanaclinic.ru/club/articles/club - падает в 404 ошибку, а https://rhanaclinic.ru/club/articles/club/ - выводит информацию по статьям.
Таким образом понятно, что вы используете какой-то комплексный компонент, скорее всего "Новости", но и "Каталог" тоже возможно (не суть важно) и просто не совсем правильно настроили пути в настройках компонента или инфоблока, а также настройку поведения компонента для 404 ошибки.